# Including images in answers?

Tags: support, status-completed

How do I include images in my answers? I want to include the syntax tree at the bottom of this Wikipedia article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_function

in one of my answers. The instructions on how to include images in answers do not help (quite frustrating!).

Comment: @prash, that worked. Thanks.

Comment: @prash Make that an answer please so Tim can accept it. :P I'll mark this Status-completed in the meantime.

Comment: @TimOsborne Remember to include a link to the source of the image as reference/attribution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see a toolbar just above the edit window. The toolbar includes a couple of ways you could insert an image. You won't see such things if you use a Javascript blocker. One way is to hit Ctrl-G to insert an image.